# ACF relationship on user profile page used for allowed access

Tags: php, plugin-development, advanced-custom-fields

I have an ACF relationship field set to show on the User Role (user's profile page). From there we can select what forums the user can access, if a forum is not given to a user then access to that forum is denied.
The ACF field is set to Post Object.

I have the following code in page.php, this is the page that is used for the forums. 
The code below should check the field "forum_access" and if a user has access to the given forum and allow access.

Unfortunately, it's not working correctly. If a user is not logged in they still have access.

```
<?php 
$is_allowed_access = get_field('forum_access');
$show_content = true;
if ( !is_user_logged_in() && $is_allowed_access) {
    $show_content = false;
}elseif( is_user_logged_in() && $is_allowed_access ){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    $show_content = false;
    foreach( $is_allowed_access as $user_allowed ){
        if( $user_allowed['ID'] == $current_user->ID ){
            $show_content = true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
?>
<?php if( $show_content ){ ?>
  Allowed
<?php } else { ?>
  Denied
<?php } ?>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've double checked the code and still can't find an issue. Can anyone spot anything wrong here?

Comment: Try without the `elseif` like so: `$show_content = ( is_user_logged_in() || empty( $is_allowed_access ) ); if ( $show_content ) { $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); ... your code ... }`

Comment: The particular feature that a not logged on user should be denied access is handled elsewhere - Use for instance the plugin My Private Site: https://wordpress.org/plugins/jonradio-private-site/